# Конвертация из String в тип соответствующего поля

Tags: java

У меня есть property файл и считывая его по ключу я получаю String и при помощи рефлексии я хочу засетать значения в п поле которое другого типа, как мне кастить String в другой тип данных

```
public void setAnnotatedFields(Map<Class<?>, Object> swarm) throws IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        propertySourceConfig.readPropertyFile();
        for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, Object> entry : swarm.entrySet()) {
            Class<?> value = entry.getValue().getClass();
            Field[] declaredFields = value.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : declaredFields) {
                if (field.getAnnotation(ConfigProperty.class) != null) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
                    ConfigProperty annotation = field.getAnnotation(ConfigProperty.class);
                    String propertyValue = propertySourceConfig.getPropertyValue(annotation.configName());
                    field.set(entry.getValue(), fieldType.cast(propertyValue));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: на текущий момент при выполнении кода: Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 0):

"как мне кастить String в другой тип данных?"
у класса String есть статический метод valueOf(), который принимает на вход все примитивные типы данных и парсит их в строку.
Если же вам нужно "скастить" например int в String, то у каждого примитива в java есть обертка, у которых куча полезных методов. Например: вы можете привести String к int следующим способом: Integer.parseInt("10");
Но будьте аккуратно, тут всегда есть вероятность выброса исключения: NumberFormatException, который выбрасывается, в случае если в строке, которую вы передаете в аргументе, будет недопустимое значение.

Comment: если я заранее не знаю в какой тип данных мне нужно конвертировать, то есть, я могу над всеми 
 полями с разными типами поставить аннотацию и мне для каждого нужно будет делать if или case?

Comment: Если вы парсите в String, то не надо, так как метод valueOf() - перегруженный. Если же из String, то тут нужно подумать, над допустимыми значениями. Откуда они приходят к вам? Если, например, из консоли, думаю что проверять каждый ответ на тип, не лучшее решение. Я бы лучше ограничил ввод для пользователя и проверял бы что он вводит на стадии ввода, а не на стадии парсинга. Откуда вы получаете данные, которые хотите парсить?

Comment: из property файла

Comment: Так если вы хардкодите в проперти файл константу, вы же знаете ее тип, разве нет?